# How can I get a value of an action class from another

Tags: java, servlets, struts-1

I have two action classes

```
public class TokenAction extends Action {
    private ActionForward getToken(ActionMapping actionMapping, ActionForm actionForm, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        String token = generateToken();
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.getWriter().print(token);

        return null;
    }
```

and

```
public class ActionTwo extends Action{
    private ActionForward doSomething(ActionMapping actionMapping, ActionForm actionForm, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)  {
        token = ???
        return actionMapping.findForward("page");
    }

}
```

How can I get in ActionTwo from TokenAction?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, in Java there are multiple ways to pass objects across contexts, the most popular being likely:

- through static variables (not recommended)
- through shared parameter maps
- through a controller object

In your case, since the parameters passed to the methods seem to have a lifetime that encompasses both calls (although it's hard to say without the specifics), you should probably store them in the parameters (`HttpServletResponse` isn't very useful for that purpose, but the `ActionMapping` and `ActionForm` likely are). If your `Action`s are created in the context of some controller, you could use the controller to pass the parameter instead.